# Ways to refer to a database, collection, and document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

1. `use <databasename>` will set a variable `db` to be the database
   specified by `<databasename>`, so the database can be referred to
   the variable `db`.

   I wonder if a collection or document can also be
   referred to by a variable, and if yes, how?
2. Every object in a MongoDB server has an identifier `_id`. If I am correct, a database, a collection and a document are objects.

   How are   the identifier of an object used in practice?
3. Both a database and a collection have a name. So we can refer to a
   collection via its name e.g. `mydb.mycollection`.

   Does a document also have a name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A collection consists of several documents so a document as such do not have any name. _id distinguishes the documents. To fetch any particular document, you can filter it on the basis of _id or the data stored in it.
Referencing the db and then the collection in selected db will give you the required document.